# FreeBSD. nginx, php-fpm, PDO_mysql driver does not work

Tags: mysql, nginx, pdo, php

Problems with PDO driver on php-fpm, with nginx on FreeBSD

See php modules:

```
#php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql <-is here 0_o
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
sqlite3
...

[Zend Modules]
```

PDO is enabled:
    # php --ri pdo

```
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
```

PHP FPM information

```
# php-fpm -i
...
PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: c85105d7c6f7d70d609bb4c000257868a40840ab $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.8.7.2
...
```

And i take this error:

```
2014/12/24 21:46:17 [error] 99501#0: *3930 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver
' in /usr/home/anmall/bitmachinegewerh/client/lib/user/profile.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/home/anmall/bitmachinegewerh/client/lib/user/profile.php(22): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', '***', '****', Array)
#1 /usr/home/anmall/bitmachinegewerh/client/public/awesome.php(10): User->connectDB()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /usr/home/anmall/bitmachinegewerh/client/lib/user/profile.php on line 22" while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.48.252.89, server: bitmach
inegewerh.su, request: "POST /client/public/awesome.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "bitmachinegewerh.su", referrer: "http://bitmachinegewerh
.su/client/public/login.php"
```

Finally i dont see PDO_Mysql driver in phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Archlinux and ran into the same issue.

I fixed it by restarting `php-fpm` service.

Answer (score 0):

I might be the mysql's socket problem, if so 
1:
log into mysql from terminal and try to find the socket's place
`mysql -u root -p`

and run this query to find out
2:
`show variables like '%socket%';`

now you should change your php.ini's settings on mysql's socket 
find your effective php.ini by
3:
`php --ini`

and add or edit php.ini file found in step 3.
4:
`pdo_mysql.default_socket=<THE PATH IN STEP 2>`

Thanks to 
https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/4448/error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory